# Assets Warning - The image set name xxx is used by multiple image sets

Tags: ios, xcode

**Just curious, apologize in advance if bothered.**

Getting the warning When i using same name for multiple image sets. I already know using different names will solve the problem. But i am wandering what is the behavior of Xcode what if i don't do that by still keeping two image sets with the same name and run project. Which image set will be chosen ?

**EDIT**

Here is [Relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Apple Asset Catalog Format Reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html):

> For any target in an Xcode project, the fully qualified name of an
>   asset must be unique across all the asset catalogs and across all
>   asset types. For example, it is an error to have an image set folder
>   in one asset catalog called Llama.imageset and an image set with the
>   same name in the same catalog or in a different catalog that is part
>   of the same target. Similarly, it is an error to have both an image
>   set folder called Llama.imageset and an app icon folder called
>   Llama.appiconset in the same catalog or in a different catalog that is
>   part of the same target.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question while looking for a way to fix the issue:

### The image set name xxx is used by multiple image sets

I know my post does not answer the question asked here but I wanted to leave this response here just in case someone else happens to find this post as I did while searching for a solution.

I was moving images from one project to another when this warning appeared. It was apparently due to having 2x & 3x sizes with the same name.

However, I had the exact same images in another project named in exactly the same way without seeing this warning.

X-code had already appended the file names in the *finder directory* by adding “-1” and “-2” to the name when I moved the images into the Assets folder.

While back inside of x-Code I had all images in the Assets folder with the same name.

Looking here,

### Target>Build Phases>Copy Bundle Resources

[image: The way the folder appeared after I deleted the file]

### I found there were Two items being copied

"*Assets.xcassets*" and "*Preview Assets.xcassets*”

I deleted the “*Preview Assets.xcassets*” and the problem was resolved.

I hope this helps someone.